# EOFException from ObjectInputStream constructor

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, objectinputstream

I have an app that serializes and reads/writes some custom objects in Java.

One of my clients has a particular file (only one) that is throwing a `EOFException` whenever the file is read into the `ObjectInputStream` constructor.

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot to mention that I am receiving the file through this code:

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
```

So, the File does exist as far as `File#listFiles()` is retrieving it.

So `file` in the code below is received from the loop:

```
for(File file : files)
```

Thus, the `IOException` shouldn't be from the file being missing (because why would `listFiles()` return it?).

END-EDIT
I figured this may be due to a glitch from a failed-partial-write of the object, so I added code to delete the problem file if there is a `EOFException`:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);) {
    // Do stuff...
} catch (IOException e) {
    if(e instanceof EOFException) {
       file.delete();
    }
    ErrorHandler.handleError(e);
}
```

Although this code executes successfully, it does not actually delete the file. (I still see the error in logs constantly). So, I opted to have my client manually search for and delete this file. He searched, found it, and deleted it. He confirmed to me that it successfully deleted the file. However, even after he manually deleted it, this error still pops up!

Although this is a Java program, my suspicion is this is a Windows file-system glitch so Java won't have much to do with this. Does anyone have experience with "ghost" files that seem to be there but aren't? Or that seem to get deleted but don't?

This is a confusing problem. Impossible for me to reproduce.

Comment: Um, perhaps the `IOException` is "File not found".

Comment: First rule of asking for help on SO is to post the _entire_ stack trace.  Regardless, notice that the EOF is occurring in `ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream`, so the OIS is "priming the pump", so to speak.  Clearly the file does not contain enough data to make a complete object, and is either empty or corrupted, or locked exclusively by another process, which would explain why you can't delete it.

Comment: @BrianRoach, sorry. I forgot to add some crucial details to the question. But the `IOException` wouldn't be from file not found. Please read the edit above.

Comment: @JimGarrison, that would make sense, except `file.delete()` does not throw an error. Plus, that wouldn't explain why my client (through Windows Explorer) thought he deleted the file but didn't.

Comment: File.delete() doesn't throw exceptions. It returns a boolean.

Comment: In my real application, yes, I am checking the boolean, and yes, `file.delete()` returns true.

Comment: When you caught the EOFException the file was still open. Some platforms don't let you delete open files.

Answer (score 0):

The file is empty, or doesn't contain a complete object stream header. In either event it is corrupt, and you should have detected that when you wrote it.

Probably you failed to close the `ObjectOutputStream` when you created the file.

Comment: A failed close should cause `ObjectInputStream#readObject()` to throw an error, but this error is being thrown on the constructor, not on `readObject()`. The question is, why would the constructor throw an error?

Comment: You're mistaken. A failed close could cause either readObject() or the constructor to throw an exception. There's a stream header that's read by the constructor. See the Javadoc. If it isn't there completely, you get what you got. What you should be investigating is the failed close.